# How can I look for PhD offers in the USA?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states

I am a French citizen who is interested in a PhD in the US, Canada or Australia, in the field of geography, water management and protection, environmental problematics, land management...

But it seems really hard to find PhD offers, especially when you are a foreigner. I wonder if this is because we are in a bad period, where most of the offers are closed at the beginning of the year?

I get the feeling that most PhD candidates are recruited internally. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Try findaphd.com.

Comment: At many US & Canadian universities, students who are interested in doing a doctorate apply to a department at a particular university;  only once they are accepted do they join a particular laboratory/research group.  The key phrase here is "graduate admissions";  Google "graduate admissions [field] [university]" to find out more about the application procedure for a particular department at a particular university.

Comment: Okay so if I understand things correctly, I am first supposed to reach out to a laboratory, and if they accept my profile they might offer me a phd position? The topic of which they will choose for me. I will do as you say and google graduate admission, I just hope the process is free since it might lead to nothing.

Comment: I’m voting to reopen this question, because it has a direct and useful answer: To first approximation, there is no such thing as a “PhD position” in the United States, because “PhD student” is not considered a job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the United States, you will not often find advertisements for one PhD positions. This is because graduate admissions are handled at the *departmental* level, rather than at the PI level. So, if you can find departments whose research interests line up with your own, you can apply. Note that there are usually one or two deadlines per year (which vary from school to school!), so make sure your application (including test scores) is ready by then.

Answer (score 1):

I know only a little about applications to grad programs in the EU, but it's very different from the US (and Canada). In general you apply to a *program*, not a particular lab or advisor, although having advance contact with a potential advisor is often advantageous during the admissions process. Most US PhD programs admit only beginning in the Fall term, with application deadlines typically the previous January. So if you are trying to apply for Fall 2018, you need to be filing applications now. But there is no particular disadvantage to being an EU student, assuming your application is competitive otherwise and you speak English well.

Nearly all US programs require GRE scores, so you also need to have taken these already. If you have additional questions about a particular program, you should direct them to the "graduate director" or "director of graduate studies."

Comment: _So if you are trying to apply for Fall 2018, you need to be filing applications now_ — In fact, many Fall 2018 application deadlines have already passed.  (The deadline for my department's PhD program was December 15.)

Comment: @JeffE This is true, but a strong applicant can often be given consideration with a late application.